# Can you show any examples of a 兼務発令書 in English?

Tags: translation

This is in a university context. Professors will be given an extra post (mostly in name) and the notification will be sent to them in English. I have not been able to find any examples of how this would be translated/laid out.

Comment: I have an 委属依頼文書 which is a similar document, but it's in Japanese. Our university doesn't do much in English.

Comment: Unless I am missing something, your question is about English (and finding sample documents in English), not Japanese. I am afraid that would make it off-topic.

Comment: I see many questions asking for explanations of Japanese words, sentences, grammar, etc. on this site. They are all asked and answered in English. My query is not different - in my case, I am merely asking for more. A document.

Comment: @Kyle: you misunderstand me: it is perfectly fine to be asking questions and answering them in English, or even to ask for help translating specific terms in English. But your query is for monolingual English documents that simply happen to match a type of Japanese document.

Comment: @Dave Exactly. That's my problem. The kind of document itself is unique to Japanese, at least in my limited experience. Where else could I find a community that could answer this type of question?

Comment: @Kyle http://reddit.com/r/translator